# Any free, open-source manager-side SNMP Java libraries besides SNMP4J?

Tags: java, snmp

I have the [**SNMP4J**](http://www.snmp4j.org/) distribution, which looks at first glance to be capable and current. For good, healthy due diligence on my client's behalf, though, I'd just as soon see one or two more such libraries.

Anybody know of any other SNMP libraries written in Java? This would be for the manager side; the agent side is in good shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of SNMP java stacks.  Some quick googling or [searching on FreshMeat](http://freecode.com/search?q=snmp+java&submit=Search) will show you quite a few.

Comment: Thank you, Wes. I'm very glad to see you on this group.

Comment: Yeah...  freshmeat changed to freecode and now freecode is no longer being updated.  So, sadly, the link will never be full right again.